# How can I set the environment variable in request header for curl?

Tags: bash, curl, http-headers, environment-variables

How can I set the environment variable in request header for curl

```
curl --location --request POST 'test.example.com' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'access_token: "${SOME_ENV_TOKEN}"' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Og=='
```

Not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `--header "access_token: \"${SOME_ENV_TOKEN}\""`

The `'` quotes disable variable expansion in sh.

Comment: --header "access_token: "${SOME_ENV_TOKEN}"" in deed worked. Thanks